# OCaml Entire Statement Not Being Evaluated

Tags: ocaml

I wrote a function that subtracts 2 arrays which represent numbers. Whenever the second condition in the match is hit ( _, true ), it executes the inner statements and then performs a "continue". Meaning it wont go down and execute "print_endline "After" ......rest; However it works fine with the other two, to update the position in the array. How could I fix this?

```
let subtract_arrays ~array1 ~array2 = 
      let length = Array.length array1 in 
      let newArray = Array.make length 0 in 
      let carry = ref false in 
      Core.Array.rev_inplace array1;
      Core.Array.rev_inplace array2;
      for i = 0 to length - 1 do 
        print_endline ("I is: " ^ (string_of_int i));
        let result = ref 0 in
        let bool1 = array1.(i) = 0 && array2.(i) = 0 in
        let bool2 = array1.(i) = 0 || ( array1.(i) < array2.(i) ) in
        print_endline "Before";
        match ( bool1, bool2 ) with 
          | ( true, _ ) -> 
            (match !carry with 
              | true ->  result := 1; carry := false; 
              | false -> result := 0);
          | ( _, true ) -> 
            result := array1.(i) + 10 - array2.(i);
            (match array1.(i + 1) with 
              | 0 -> array1.(i + 1) <- 9;
              | _ -> array1.(i + 1) <- array1.(i + 1) - 1)
          | ( _ ,  _  ) ->
            result := array1.(i) - array2.(i) - (if !carry then 1 else 0);
            carry := false;
        print_endline "After";
        print_endline ("-- Middle Result is : " ^ (string_of_int !result));
        match 0 > !result with 
        | true  -> newArray.(i) <- -1 * !result; carry := true; print_endline ("True Result is : " ^ (string_of_int !result)); 
        | false -> newArray.(i) <- !result; print_endline ("False Result is : " ^ (string_of_int !result));
      print_endline ("Ending I is: " ^ (string_of_int i));
      done;
      Core.Array.rev_inplace newArray;
      newArray
        ;;


let printline_int x =
    print_endline (string_of_int x )
;;

let () =
  let array1 = [|9; 9; 9; 1;|] in
  let array2 = [|0; 0; 0; 5;|] in
  subtract_arrays ~array1:array1 ~array2:array2 |> Array.iter printline_int;;
```

Result i'm getting

```
I is: 0              
Before
I is: 1
Before
After
-- Middle Result is : 8
False Result is : 8
Ending I is: 1
I is: 2
Before
After
-- Middle Result is : 9
False Result is : 9
Ending I is: 2
I is: 3
Before
After
-- Middle Result is : 9
False Result is : 9
Ending I is: 3
9
9
8
0
```

Answer (score 2):

OCaml is not white-space sensitive, so the indentation level of each line does not inform the compiler of which block it belongs to. Furthermore, `;` is not a statement terminator (OCaml doesn't even have statements), but a sequence operator which expects an expression before and after the operator. Your liberal use of semicolons is making the compiler interpret the program very differently than you do.

In particular, the semicolon following `curry := false` will include `print_endline "After"`, and the rest of that sequence of expressions (until `done`), in the last branch of the `match`. This is not the only problem, however.

A good tip is to use [ocp-indent](https://www.typerex.org/ocp-indent.html) on your code, which will automatically indent the code according to how the compiler will interpret it.

It's also a good idea to avoid using the imperative features of OCaml unless you need them, since it's very easy to make mistakes like this.

Comment: You've correctly identified that the indentation doesn't match the actual nesting, but semicolons aren't the problem. The problem is the scope of the `match` constructs.

Comment: @Gilles Sure, you can break out of the scope in other ways too, such as by nesting `match` expressions. But he seems aware of that since there are nested `match` expressions which are enclosed in parentheses. So in _this_ case, it seems the problem is caused by not understanding semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

As [glennsl noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276435), the indentation of your code doesn't match the actual control flow. I think the indentation reflects what the code should be doing but I haven't tested it.

The problem is the scope of `match`: it has lower precedence than semicolons, so with code like this:

```
match x with
| false -> print_endline "false"
| true -> print_endline "in match"; print_endline "still in match";
print_endline "still in match despite the indentation"
```

the message "still in match despite the indentation" is printed only in the `true` case. You need to put parentheses or `begin`/`end` around the match (or put it in a function, or assign the result with `let`, or whatever makes sense to get the syntax right).

```
let subtract_arrays ~array1 ~array2 =
  let length = Array.length array1 in
  let newArray = Array.make length 0 in
  let carry = ref false in
  Core.Array.rev_inplace array1;
  Core.Array.rev_inplace array2;
  for i = 0 to length - 1 do
    print_endline ("I is: " ^ (string_of_int i));
    let result = ref 0 in
    let bool1 = array1.(i) = 0 && array2.(i) = 0 in
    let bool2 = array1.(i) = 0 || ( array1.(i) < array2.(i) ) in
    print_endline "Before";
    begin match ( bool1, bool2 ) with
      | ( true, _ ) ->
        (match !carry with
          | true ->  result := 1; carry := false;
          | false -> result := 0);
      | ( _, true ) ->
        result := array1.(i) + 10 - array2.(i);
        (match array1.(i + 1) with
          | 0 -> array1.(i + 1) <- 9;
          | _ -> array1.(i + 1) <- array1.(i + 1) - 1)
      | ( _ ,  _  ) ->
        result := array1.(i) - array2.(i) - (if !carry then 1 else 0);
        carry := false;
    end;
    print_endline "After";
    print_endline ("-- Middle Result is : " ^ (string_of_int !result));
    begin match 0 > !result with
    | true  -> newArray.(i) <- -1 * !result; carry := true; print_endline ("True Result is : " ^ (string_of_int !result));
    | false -> newArray.(i) <- !result; print_endline ("False Result is : " ^ (string_of_int !result));
    end;
    print_endline ("Ending I is: " ^ (string_of_int i));
  done;
  Core.Array.rev_inplace newArray;
  newArray
;;
```

Using `match` for booleans is a bit strange. The code would be easier to understand with `if`. Note that unlike `match`, `if` binds more tightly than semicolons.

Another way in which your code is hard to read is that it uses mutable variables where they aren't needed. This makes it harder to track how values are computed. Making `carry` a reference is justified because the value has to carry through to the next iteration of the loop (though it may be more readable to use a recursive function instead of the loop). But `result` has no business being a reference: you only assign it once.

```
let subtract_arrays ~array1 ~array2 =
  let length = Array.length array1 in
  let newArray = Array.make length 0 in
  let carry = ref false in
  Core.Array.rev_inplace array1;
  Core.Array.rev_inplace array2;
  for i = 0 to length - 1 do
    let result =
      if array1.(i) = 0 && array2.(i) = 0 then
        let result = if !carry then 1 else 0 in
        carry := false;
        result
      else if array1.(i) = 0 || array1.(i) < array2.(i) then
        let result = array1.(i) + 10 - array2.(i) in
        array1.(i + 1) <- begin match array1.(i + 1) with
                          | 0 -> array1.(i + 1) <- 9
                          | _ -> array1.(i + 1) - 1
                          end;
        result
      else
        let result = array1.(i) - array2.(i) - (if !carry then 1 else 0) in
        carry := false;
        result
    in
    newArray.(i) <- (if 0 > result then (carry := true; -result) else result)
  done;
  Core.Array.rev_inplace newArray;
  newArray
;;
```